# Set content type authomatically when uploading to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, azure, upload, blob, content-type

I am trying to upload thousands of files to Azure storage with Python. Their content type is by default set to 'application/octet-stream'

I know I can set the content type of an individual file with (specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057593/how-to-set-content-type-for-upload-blob-in-azure-blob-storage-with-python)):

```
content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type="something")
```

But the issue is that the content type is not the same for all the files. I have images, javascript files, html files, and more than hundred other types.

How do I automatically set the content type based on the file that is sitting locally in my machine before I upload it to Azure storage blob using Python?

I know it is doable, because ***azcopy*** uploads with correct content type. (I tested)

Here is the part of the Python code I have written:

```
def upload(self, overwrite=False):
    with ThreadPool(self._num_threads) as pool:
        request_processes = []
        for local_path, remote_path in path_generator()
            blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(blob_url=remote_path, credential=credentials)
            file_extension: str = local_path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[-1]
            content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type=file_extension)
            kwargs: Dict[str, Any] = {'blob_type': 'BlockBlob',
                                      'content_settings': content_settings,
                                      'validate_content': True,
                                      'overwrite': overwrite,
                                      'timeout': self._timeout_seconds,
                                      'max_concurrency': 10}
            request_processes.append(pool.apply_async(self._sync_upload_file,
                                                          [blob_client, local_path],
                                                          kwds=kwargs))
            for req in request_processes:
                req.get(self._timeout_seconds)

    @staticmethod
    def _sync_upload_file(blob_client, local_path: str, *args, **kwargs):
        with open(local_path, "rb") as data:
            resp = blob_client.upload_blob(data, *args, **kwargs)
        return resp
```

The issue with this code is that it uses the file extension (js, html, png, etc) as content type. For example the content type of an html file should be ***text/html***

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution in this [website](https://ppolyzos.com/2015/10/27/apply-proper-content-type-to-files-in-azure-storage-containers-based-on-file-extensions/?unapproved=1876&moderation-hash=33dd79299285f55ddd533ee1a5b1bfb7#comment-1876).

They created a map (dictionary) from more than 650 file extensions to contentypes. But I still have some file types that are not present in this dictionary. Such as ".map", ".config", ".info", and a few more.